# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'childNodes' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'childNodes' of undefined or null reference..
Here i my Html & Java script Code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var sn = 1;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtSearch').keyup(function () {
            filterTable(document.getElementById("txtSearch"), document.getElementById("tbl"));
        });
        LoadGrid();
    });

    function LoadGrid() {
        var d = "Key=LoadGrid";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx",
            data: d,
            success: function (rs) {
                $("#tbody").html(rs);
            }
        });
    }

       <table class='tbl' id="tbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 50px;">
                    SN
                </th>
                <th>
                    Category
                </th>
                <th>
                    SubCategory
                </th>
                <th style="width: 50px">
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is code behind code
simply calling the function & then returning it.....

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string key = Request["key"] + "";
        if (key != "")
        {
            if (key == "LoadGrid")
            {
                Response.Write(LoadGrid());
            }
        }
    }

    public string LoadGrid()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int sn = 1;
        foreach (var item in new VendersDAL().GetAll())
        {
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td>");
            sb.Append(sn);
            sb.Append("</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>");
            sb.Append(item.VenderID);
            sb.Append("</td>");
            sb.Append("<td>");
            sb.Append(item.VenderName);
            sb.Append("</td>");

            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sn++;
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Its working fine in SQL 2008 but here in SQL 2012........ it showing Error in Jquery. i have added Jquery reference in Master page.

Comment: Is your query returning any records?

Comment: yes, it returns the all record but when binding html in JQuery showing error

Comment: <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>Alfa</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>Bravo</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>Charly</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>Dazy</td></tr>

Comment: It sounds like *something* is `null` or `undefined`, make sure `rs` in your callback is *definitely* not null.